# Quirky Primes Test

Tags: prime-numbers

Wrote a program to list all primes $n$ below $1,000,000$ and noticed they never satisfied (except $n=5$)

$\frac {n-1}2 \equiv 2 \pmod{10}$

or

$\frac {n-1}2 \equiv 7 \pmod{10}$

Is that true for all primes? Thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int isPrimeNumber(int number)
{
    int iLoop = 0;
    int iPrimeFlag = 1;

    if (number <= 1)
    {
        iPrimeFlag = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        for (iLoop = 2; iLoop < number; iLoop++)
        {
            if ((number % iLoop) == 0)
            {
                iPrimeFlag = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return iPrimeFlag;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv)
{
    uint64_t n, i, m;

    for (n = 2; n < 1000000; n++)
    {
        if (isPrimeNumber(n) == 1)
        {
            i = (n - 1) / 2;
            m = i % 10;

            if (m == 2 || m == 7)
            {                    
                printf("n=%llu i=%llu\n", n, i);
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: yes, if that was the case, you would have $5|n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do it.  Equivalence $\pmod n$ distributes over multiplication, addition and subtraction (but *not* division) so

$\frac {n-1}2 \equiv 2 \pmod{10}\implies$

$2(\frac {n-1}2) + \equiv 2\cdot 2 + 1 \pmod {10}\implies$

$n \equiv 5 \pmod {10}$

And the *definition* of $a\equiv b\pmod n$ is $n\mid a-b$ so

$10 \mid n-5$.

Now $10 = 2\cdot 5$ so that means $2|n-5$ and $5|n-5$.

And if $a|b$ then $a|b \pm ka$ for any multiple $ka$ of $a$.

so $5|(n-5) \implies 5|(n-5)+ 5\implies 5|n$.

But if $n$ is prime that's only possible if $n = 5$.

Can you do the other one.

Answer (score 1):

Your two congruences simplify to $n\equiv5\bmod10$, which is obviously not true for any prime except $5$.

Comment: Test n=15 in the first congruence and n=5 in the second.  Right idea, wrong execution.